# iOS VPN On Demand: Only outside company

Tags: ios, vpn

I was reading about the VPN On Demand feature built on the latest versions of iOS.

The problem here is: We run a VPN to access a WebApp hosted in-house on a subdomain like `salexxx.company.net` that has an A record to an internal IP of your network (eg. `172.20.1.100`). In order for someone to access the WebApp he needs to be a) connected to our network directly, or b) connected to the VPN.

We've zero interest in having every request coming from user devices going through the VPN (way much traffic). iOS VPN On Demand seems to solve the issue, however when I'm at the company office and try to access the domain the phone also fires the VPN... Causing unnecessary redundancy on the network.

- Is it possible to tell the devices to only connect to the VPN if they're outside of the company network?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an On Demand rule to disconnect in case the SSID of the Wi-Fi you're connected to matches with the one used on your company network.

```
NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect *disconnectOnCompanyNetworkRule = [[NEOnDemandRuleDisconnect alloc] init];
disconnectOnCompanyNetworkRule.SSIDMatch = @[@"company_network_name"];
```

If you're using configuration profiles, you can also add that rule to your profile as specified on the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW36

The Apple Configurator application doesn't have the ability to add these rules, you'll need to open the profile with some text editor to add these rules. And you want to add something like this to it:

```
<key>OnDemandEnabled</key>
<integer>1</integer>
<key>OnDemandRules</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Disconnect</string>
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>WiFi</string>
        <key>SSIDMatch</key>
        <array>
            <string>Company WiFi</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>                  
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>WiFi</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>Action</key>
        <string>Connect</string>
        <key>InterfaceTypeMatch</key>
        <string>Cellular</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: It's a WebApp I was talking on the "vpn on demand" feature available for domains via apple configurator profiles. It allows us to add specific domains that will trigger a VPN connection, however I don't see how I can make it only happen outside the company..

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were talking about the NetworkExtension Framework from the iOS SDK. Anyways, it's also possible to do that with the configuration profile. You can add the same rule for disconnection matching SSID as it's explained on the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW36

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use a URLStringProbe

This uses a standard https get to determine whether or not you're already on your companies' network

```
            <key>OnDemandRules</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>Action</key>
                    <string>Ignore</string>
                    <key>URLStringProbe</key>
                    <string>https://intwebsite.yourcompany.com</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
```

It's worth pointing out that the server you quote should be available with NO redirects, and should return a 200. https is preferred, but you can use http also.

From Apple's MDM Technical reference:

> URLStringProbe. Optional. A server to probe for reachability. Redirection is not supported. The URL should be to a trusted HTTPS server. The device sends a GET request to verify that the server is reachable.

[Apple MDM Technical reference](https://www.apple.com/ie/ipad/business/docs/iOS_Deployment_Technical_Reference_EN_Feb14_UK.pdf)